# Retrieve source code from Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have four different applications on Heroku that contain a considerable amount of code each, but I do not have the original folder (/sites/example-app) on my computer. Is there anyway to download the source code from my Heroku account? I don't really want to start from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do a:

```
$ git clone <repo-url-to-heroku>
```

This will clone the application from Heroku to your local system. You can find out the url of each app by going to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps and clicking on the *Settings* icon (generally they look like `git@heroku.com:my-app-name.git`).

Comment: Thank you - worked perfectly. I will accept your answer when the system allows me to do so (9 minutes from now)